# Spread with optional chaining failing with TypeScript and Webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have an application with TypeScript bundled with webpack.

I am using spread operators:

```js
const payload = {
  ...originalList,
  byKey: {
    [listId]: {
      ...originalList?.byKey[listId],
      members: [
        ...originalList?.byKey[listId]?.members, // <== members may be undefined
        {
          id: data?.attributes?.id,
        },
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

When `members` is undefined, I get an error:

```
TypeError: can't access property Symbol.iterator of undefined
```

But this only happens on Firefox; on Chrome, for example, it pass.
May it be related to my webpack build or the tsconfig?

This is the tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": ["ES6", "dom", "esnext"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*", "./*"]
}
```

This is my webpack

```js
const webpackClientDevConfig = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client', WEBPACK_SRC_CLIENT],
  output: {
    filename: 'client-[hash:4].js',
    publicPath: WEBPACK_ROOT,
  },
  devtool: '#source-map',
  stats: 'normal',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(less|css)$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },

[…] etc.
```

I'm really curious, any help will be welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undefined isn't spreadable. So if the? triggers then the result is undefined, and your code is effectively ...undefined which obviously doesn't work.

Use ?? To coelesce to an empty array ...(thing?. Prop ?? []), Or find another way to handle null/undefined (like an if check)